# Converting a JSON string to a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a CSV file like this

```
first_name,last_name,phone
Joseph,Dean,2025550194
Elbert,Valdez,2025550148
```

Using this [csv-to-json.php](https://gist.github.com/robflaherty/1185299) from GitHub I get output like this

```
[{
    "first_name": "Joseph",
    "last_name": "Dean",
    "phone": "2025550194",
    "id": 0
}, {
    "first_name": "Elbert",
    "last_name": "Valdez",
    "phone": "2025550148",
    "id": 1
}]
```

This is almost what I want - however instead of

```
"phone": "2025550194"
```

I need

```
"phone": [{
    "type": "phone",
    "number": "2025550194"
}]
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: you need this output while you convert the csv to json or you need this after you have the json output?

Comment: @HarshSanghani It doesn't really matter - as long as the final `echo json_encode($newArray);` statement outputs the correct json I'm good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the JSON string, then you would of course first convert it to an array with:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

But probably you already have the array. You then apply this loop to it:

```
foreach($arr as &$row) {
    if (isset($row['phone'])) { // only when there is a phone number:
        $row['phone'] = [[ "type" => "phone", "number" => $row['phone'] ]];
    }
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/653949).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [csv-to-json.php](https://gist.github.com/robflaherty/1185299) code with following and you got the output that you want :-

Option 1 :-

```
// Bring it all together
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
  $d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
    if ($j == 'phone') {
        $newArray[$j] = array('type' => $j, 'number' => $d);
    } else {
        $newArray[$j] = $d;
    }

}
```

Option 2 :-

```
$json_response = [{
    "first_name": "Joseph",
    "last_name": "Dean",
    "phone": "2025550194",
    "id": 0
}, {
    "first_name": "Elbert",
    "last_name": "Valdez",
    "phone": "2025550148",
    "id": 1
}];

$result         = json_decode($json_response);
$final_result   = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $row['phone']   = array('type' => 'phone', 'number' => $row['phone']);
    $final_result[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($final_result);
```

It may help you.

Comment: @Daniel can you please add your final foreach loop that will used in csv to json?

Comment: @Daniel or you can try the second option.

Comment: your 2nd solution would also work (+1). I would just add a condition to make sure the 'phone' key exists.